# Node.js forever with environment variable

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, forever

The command I run on my server to start my node app is:

```
sudo IS_PROD=1 node app.js
```

I have forever installed but can't seem to pass in the environment variable.

```
sudo IS_PROD=1 forever node app.js
```

Doesn't seem to do the trick.  I have tried several varieties of this.  How do I either execute this command successfully or permanently set the environment variable?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

First of all you should skip the `node` thing in you command, it should not be there, you should not be able to execute that. [forever](/questions/tagged/forever) automatically starts your script using [nodejs](/questions/tagged/nodejs). Instead you should do like this;

```
sudo IS_PROD=1 forever app.js
```

Probably you, instead of starting your server in foreground, will want to start your server as a daemon. eg.

```
sudo IS_PROD=1 forever start app.js
```

This will create a process in the background that will watch your node app and restart it when it exits. For more information see the [readme](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever#usage).

Both of these methods preserves the environment variables, just like when you are just using `node`.

Comment: I've got a small question, as i assume this env var is preserved on each server restart made by forever, can i somehow pass a different variable for the case of restart, not first startup. I just want do make some filewritings on first startup (Uglifying) and than do not repeat it on restarts.

Comment: True. It was my issue. I simply didn't enter `start`. 
*WRONG*: `NODE_ENV="production" forever bin/www`.
*CORRECT*: `NODE_ENV="production" forever start bin/www`

Answer (score 18):

app.js:

```
console.log(process.env.IS_PROD);
```

Using `node` (v0.8.21)

```
$ node app.js
undefined

$ IS_PROD=1 node app.js
1

$ sudo IS_PROD=1 node app.js
1
```

Using `forever` (v0.10.0)

```
$ forever app.js
undefined

$ IS_PROD=1 forever app.js
1

$ sudo IS_PROD=1 forever app.js
1
```

[Documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_env):

> **process.env**
>
> An object containing the user environment. See environ(7).

Comment: This code should test as well if process is killed and restarted by forever and then check is variables are still there imo :)