# How to set environment variables to get forever run meteorjs

Tags: node.js, meteor, environment-variables, forever

How do you set the environment variables to get forever run meteorjs?
If I do an export and run forever, like so

```
export PORT=80 MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:3002/appname

sudo forever -f start bundle/main.js
```

forever will not run the meteorjs bundle with node:

```
/Users/../bundle/server/server.js:166
throw new Error("MONGO_URL must be set in environment");
      ^
Error: MONGO_URL must be set in environment
at run (/Users/../bundle/server/server.js:166:11)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/../bundle/server/server.js:331:1)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
at require (module.js:380:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/../bundle/main.js:1:63)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 8
```

If I run it directly, it runs smoothly:

```
sudo PORT=80 MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:3002/appname ROOT_URL=http://myapp.com node bundle/main.js
```

If I do it like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14618054/node-js-forever-with-environment-variable/15223221#15223221) it works. But why doesn't it work with the export statement?
Is there a way to tell forever a config file to read those settings? I don't see a way in the [forever docs](https://npmjs.org/package/forever).

Comment: The reason it does not work is that the environment variables are not inherited by the sudo process. Check out man sudo or have a look [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16084/what-environment-do-i-get-with-sudo).

Answer (score 7):

You can run forever just like node. Try following

```
sudo PORT=80 MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:3002/appname ROOT_URL=http://myapp.com forever -f start bundle/main.js
```

Comment: That works. Is there no way to do it in different steps? Or give forever a config-file?

Comment: Check out this [link](http://blog.nodejitsu.com/keep-a-nodejs-server-up-with-forever) to read about how forever could be used. Please accept my answer above if it helps.