# Discord.js can't launch bot with process.env on the server with forever, but it works on my local drive via Visual Studio without problems

Tags: node.js, authentication, discord.js, environment-variables, forever

I have problem launching bot on the server with forever...
I'm using `process.env` where I store BOT Token and Instagram login credentials.
However on the server i cannot made bot work due this error..

```
(node:30365) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'padLevels' of module exports inside circular dependency
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
ig-bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/Client.js:228
    if (!token || typeof token !== 'string') throw new Error('TOKEN_INVALID');
                                                   ^

Error [TOKEN_INVALID]: An invalid token was provided.
    at Client.login (ig-bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/Client.js:228:52)
    at Object.<anonymous> (ig-bot/ig.js:64:8)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1092:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1121:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:813:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:76:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  [Symbol(code)]: 'TOKEN_INVALID'
}
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 1
error: Script restart attempt #1
ig-bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/Client.js:228
    if (!token || typeof token !== 'string') throw new Error('TOKEN_INVALID');
                                                   ^

Error [TOKEN_INVALID]: An invalid token was provided.
    at Client.login (ig-bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/Client.js:228:52)
    at Object.<anonymous> (ig-bot/ig.js:64:8)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1092:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1121:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:813:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:76:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  [Symbol(code)]: 'TOKEN_INVALID'
}
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 1
```

It says token is invalid, but it really does not make any sense because it works on my PC and i can run the code via visual studio without problem. Same folder of the bot has trouble running on my server (usually i use config.json for token, but this time i need .env file)

//Process ENV code

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config({ path: './process.env' });
const username = process.env.IGUSERNAME
const password = process.env.IGPASSWORD
const TOKEN = process.env.TOKEN

client.login(TOKEN);
```

I tried `ENV=production forever start yourApp.js` `forever -c "node -r dotenv/config" --workingDir app-workdir-path start app.js` but none of these worked for me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After several hours I was able to find a solution.

```
const path = require('path')
require('dotenv').config({ path: path.resolve(__dirname, '.env') })
```

This code will force to run your `.env` file from your script directory. `console.log(__dirname)` will return your `path` to the .js file. It solved the whole problem.

```
//Full code example

const path = require('path')
require('dotenv').config({ path: path.resolve(__dirname, '.env') })
const TOKEN = process.env.TOKEN
 
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS] });

client.on('ready', () => {
    client.user.setActivity("WE DID IT!", { type: 'PLAYING' });
    client.guilds.cache.forEach(guild => {
    let channel = guild.channels.cache.get('channelID')
    channel.send(`I'm finally ready!`);
    console.log('Wohoo! Bot is online!')
    })
})

// Login to Discord with your client's token
client.login(TOKEN);
```

Answer (score 0):

Based off of this answer I believe you should do `sudo IS_PROD=1 forever start yourapp.js`

[Node.js forever with environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14618054/node-js-forever-with-environment-variable)

Comment: Same problem... this also is not working

Comment: honestly, i use PM2 (which is similar to forever) with a .env file in my root dir and i havent had any issues... when i google around people just say to run it like you would run regular node with environment variables

Comment: Not sure what is PM2, I'm fine with forever but i can't find way to make it work... 
NODE_ENV=production forever ig-bot/ig.js is also not working...

Comment: PM2 is a process manager that lets you run things indefinitely. try passing your environment variables through the command line like `ENV=production forever start yourApp.js`, but it is possible forever just does not like dotenv or environment variables at all

Comment: Ugh this is really weird... i tried simple node ig-bot/ig.js and it says same error ... invalid token.. but it literally does not make sense, it's literraly same copy that is working on my desktop via Visual Studio Code... I don't understand what the hell is going on.

Comment: try changing your dotenv config code to `dotenv.config({ path: '..env' });` on your server and make sure your env file is in the root directory (same as ig.js) and rename it to just `.env`. dotenv expects the file to be a hidden file with no name just .env

Comment: Same... this is really weird glitch. I even tried simple require('dotenv').config() and renamed env file to just `.env`   and still the same issue...

Comment: yeah, very weird... i would recommend trying pm2 as an alternative, it is an npm package that should let you do what you need to: https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/quick-start/

Comment: I tried also.. didn't worked... even simple node ig-bot/ig.js is saying same shit... it can't read the token... This is maybe some .js glitch but how to fix it?